# How would I order by most weighted matches?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table where I tried to find users that have a matching love or a matching want.

```
create table info (id integer, love text[], want text[]);
insert into info (id, love, want) values (1, '{run, bike, swim}', '{dance, bike. sit}');
insert into info (id, love, want) values (2, '{sit, bike, dance}', '{run}');
insert into info (id, love, want) values (3, '{jump. hike, swim}', '{bike}');
select * from info where '{sit, hike, drive}' && love or '{bike, eat, draw}' && want;
```

I want to return them in order by the number of matches, but weight the loves 2x as much as the wants.  Meaning if a match is found where there are 3 matching wants but 2 matching loves, the match with 2 matching loves would be weighted higher.  How would I do that?

Also, would it be possible to shuffle the results for each weighting level?  For example, if 5 rows have a weighting of of 3 and 8 rows a weighting of 4, I would return the 8 rows with a weighting of 4 before the 5 rows with the weighting of 3, but the order for the 8 rows and 5 rows would be random.

Comment: Normalize the data model so that you avoid arrays.

Comment: How would you normalize it to remove arrays?  Are you saying create a table love with columns run, bike, dance, sit, etc?

Comment: I mean to create a table that contains `info_id`, what it is that is loved or wanted and a third column that says whether it is a love or want. There would be one such entry for everything that is wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to order them by `<nr love matches> * <love weight> + <nr want matches> * <want weight>`

There is no native function in PostgreSQL to calculate the intersection of an array, but you can easily add that with something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_intersect(anyarray, anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray
language sql
as $function$
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) INTERSECT SELECT unnest($2));
$function$;
```

After that, you can query the table like

```
SELECT
    *,
    cardinality(array_intersect('{sit, hike, drive}', love)) * 2 
      + cardinality(array_intersect('{sit, hike, drive}', want)) 
      AS weight
FROM info
WHERE
    '{sit, hike, drive}' && love
    OR '{bike, eat, draw}' && want
ORDER BY
    weight DESC,
    RANDOM()
```

Note: this could become quite inefficient over a large dataset.